# Can't Import Tensor Flow in Anaconda 3.6 on Windows 10

Tags: python, tensorflow

I just installed CUDA 92 CUDANN and Tensor Flow on my Windows 10 laptop.

I am unable to import tensor flow in Python.  I get a trace from Python that says:

> can't load a dll

But it doesn't say which one it is.  Here is a directory listing the trace I received.  Can you help.

> PS C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v9.2\bin> python
>   Python 3.6.0 |Anaconda 4.3.0 (64-bit)| (default, Dec 23 2016,
>   11:57:41) [MSC v.1900 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 Type "help",
>   "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>   import tensorflow as tf
>   Traceback (most recent call last):
>     File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py", line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *
>     File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 18, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()
>     File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py", line 17, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)
>     File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
>   ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

> Traceback (most recent call last):   File "", line 1, in
>      File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow__init__.py", line 24, in
>   
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow  # pylint: disable=unused-import   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python__init__.py", line
>   49, in 
>       from tensorflow.python import pywrap_tensorflow   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 74, in 
>       raise ImportError(msg) ImportError: Traceback (most recent call last):   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow.py",
>   line 58, in 
>       from tensorflow.python.pywrap_tensorflow_internal import *   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 18, in 
>       _pywrap_tensorflow_internal = swig_import_helper()   File "C:\Program
>   Files\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\pywrap_tensorflow_internal.py",
>   line 17, in swig_import_helper
>       return importlib.import_module(mname)   File "C:\Program Files\Anaconda3\lib\importlib__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
>       return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level) ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
>
> Failed to load the native TensorFlow runtime.
>
> See
>   https://www.tensorflow.org/install/install_sources#common_installation_problems
>
> for some common reasons and solutions.  Include the entire stack trace
>   above this error message when asking for help.

Answer (score 0):

Mostly in windows its caused by MSVCP140.dll missing if you install

[Microsoft Visual C++](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=53587)

if that doesn't help, following dependencies are also there for tensotorflow:

KERNEL32.dll

WSOCK32.dll

WS2_32.dll

SHLWAPI.dll

python35.dll

MSVCP140.dll

VCRUNTIME140.dll

api-ms-win-crt-runtime-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-heap-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-utility-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-stdio-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-string-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-math-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-convert-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-environment-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-filesystem-l1-1-0.dll

api-ms-win-crt-time-l1-1-0.dll